# Changing the default selected value in dropdownlist

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, default-value

How to change the default selected value of an drop down list. I want the default value to best seller instead of price low to high.

The code:

```
<select name="ddlSort" id="ddlSort" onchange="javascript:callSortOrder()" class="dropdown" gtbfieldid="2">
    <option selected="selected" value="">Price low to high</option>
    <option value="1">Price high to low</option>
    <option value="2">Best seller</option>
    <option value="3">Highest rating</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Do you want to change it in the HTML or change it with JavaScript?

Comment: `<option value="2" selected="selected">Best seller</option>` then remove the selected attribute from "Price low to high"

Comment: I want to change it with jquery /javascript

Answer (score 1):

Just put `selected="selected"` on the `option` you want, and remove it from the other options.

So, in your case

```
<select name="ddlSort" id="ddlSort" onchange="javascript:callSortOrder()" class="dropdown" gtbfieldid="2">
    <option value="">Price low to high</option>
    <option value="1">Price high to low</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="2">Best seller</option>
    <option value="3">Highest rating</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I cant change the code that was there already. I need to do in javascript/jquery.

Comment: If through jquery, do `$("#ddlSort").val('2);` like the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use the below markup. `selected="selected"` attribute tells the browser to select that option.

```
<select name="ddlSort" id="ddlSort" onchange="javascript:callSortOrder()" class="dropdown" gtbfieldid="2">
    <option value="">Price low to high</option>
    <option value="1">Price high to low</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="2">Best seller</option>
    <option value="3">Highest rating</option>
</select>
```

If you want to do it programmatically using jQuery try this

```
$("#ddlSort").val('2');
```

Comment: Its changing value in drop down but not changing the text for that value .

Comment: It will set the option with value '2' as selected in the dropdown. What do you actually want?

Comment: Its selecting the option 2 in dropdown but the displaying the first option (price low to high) text down.I mean not displaying the Best seller text down.

Comment: What do you mean by text down?

Comment: It is supposed to sort according to the drop down list. It is not showing the Best-seller values even if it changed the test to best-seller instead it is showing the price low to  high values.